# Invoke-WebRequest with client certificate works in Powershell but unable to do this in .NET C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, client-certificates

I'm trying to download from a specific endpoint which requires me to authenticate using a client certificate.  I am able to do this in Powershell with the following command:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $url -CertificateThumbprint "HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH"
```

However, when I try to do this in C# .NET, it returns "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.".

Below is the code I'm using to test this in .NET and I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestCertificate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            string thumbprint = "HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH";
            thumbprint = thumbprint.Replace("\u200e", string.Empty).Replace("\u200f", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty);

            X509Certificate2 Cert = GetCertificate(thumbprint);

            using (CertificateWebClient SecureClient = new CertificateWebClient(Cert))
            {
                string url = "some.endpoint";
                string s_xml = SecureClient.DownloadString(url);

                Console.WriteLine(s_xml);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string certificateThumbprint)
        {
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var cert = store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Thumbprint.ToUpper() == certificateThumbprint.ToUpper());
            store.Close();
            return cert;
        }
    }

    public class CertificateWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private readonly X509Certificate2 certificate;

        public CertificateWebClient(X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            certificate = cert;
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate X509certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
            {
                return true;
            };

            request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

The certificate is found and I set Expect100Continue to true and SecurityProtocol to Tls12, and ServerCertificateValidationCallback that returns true.  What else am I missing here?

Comment: That endpoint does support Tls12, right?

Comment: If you can get network tracing to work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing and log at the verbose level you'll see what gets send and what is received. It often offers more clues in which phase of the tls negotiation the connection blows up.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) and [Protocols in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support)

Comment: Thank you @rene.  I managed to get network trace working and now see that it throws "AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D.".  When I google on this error, I am to believe that it means that the private key cannot be accesses.  This is strange as I am able to connect using a PowerShell script.  Is .NET using a different 'user' to access the private key?  I also did a trace on the PS script and see that the server requires TLS12, which is what I'm using.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);`  as your powershell script doesn't select the LocalMachine store either.

Comment: @rene: That was exactly the problem.  I changed it to CurrentUser and it works.  Thanks for your tips!